# IS it easily possible to place fieldset elements so that the input fields begin at the same horizontal space?

Tags: html, css

I've got a fieldset like this:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Testsituation</legend>
    Field 1: <input type="text"/><br>
    My field 2: <input type="text" />
</fieldset>
```

Now my field 2's input field is displayed way right of field 1's.

My question here is: Is there an easy way to accomplish the input fields being displayed exactly under each other?

As a fiddle example for how it looks like and what I try to achieve:
http://jsfiddle.net/0pj92kxc/
(the effect that is accomplished by the table is what I'm looking for thus both input boxes at the same horizontal locatoin)

Comment: please share your work on a fiddle

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: updated with a jsfiddle example of what it looks like and what I want it to look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can archive this in different ways.

I think the Table way is not really wrong to do it, you also can just put them UNDER the the text like

***Loginname***

[ Enter your username.. ]

But if you want to stay the way you want to do, you can define a fixed width for the first text part like following:

**HTML**

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Testsituation</legend>
    <p class="field">
        <label for="f1"><span>Field 1:</span></label> <input id="f1" type="text">
    </p>
    <p class="field">
        <label for="f2"><span>Field 1:</span></label> <input id="f2" type="text">
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

**CSS**

```
.field span {
    min-width: 75px;
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cqrs10b5/4/

Answer (score 1):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0pj92kxc/1/)**

```
 <p> <label> Field 1:</label> <input type="text"></p>
 <p> <label>My field 2: </label><input type="text"></p>
```

CSS:

```
p{
    margin:5px;
   display:block;

}
label{
    width:100px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: This is the first approach I also wanted to do and then I was like "the float is bad at this point.. isn't there something else?" and then I remembered `inline-block` and changed it :-) But I like the labels, I added them to my answer, they are not really part of the answer, but better lead them to a more User-Helpfull way.